# How to write test case using jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs

**file.ts**

```
function test1(request: Request,response:Response){
  const entity  = this.test2(request)
  response.send(entity)
}

function test2(request:Request,response:Response){
  return request.originalurl
}
```

**MyScenrio**
I tried to write a test in the test1() function .test1() function not return any values the how to write the test case in this function.

Comment: Are you sure that `this.test2(request)` is supposed to work? Are both methods part of a global class or object that share the same `this` instance?

Comment: yes it's working fine

Comment: Do these two functions declare in a class or declare in the file directly? `this.test2(request);` will not call `test2` method if you declared them in a module scope directly.